# How to call this function template?

Tags: c++

```
struct Message1 {
    int a;
    int b;
};
template<class MSG_T> void RegisterMessageType() {
    MSG_T t;
}

Message1 m;
RegisterMessageType<Message1>();
```

Error message:

```
error C2909: 'RegisterMessageType': explicit instantiation of function template 
           requires return type

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. 
               Note: C++ does not support default-int

error C2768: 'RegisterMessageType' : illegal use of explicit template arguments
```

What is wrong? Thanks.

Sorry, edit again.

if i put

```
Message1 m;
RegisterMessageType<Message1>();
```

into main function, it (VS2010) can compile it Okay. But if i put it outside of main, above compiling error occurred.

Comment: @Borgleader: That's because you moved the function call into a function.

Comment: what I don't understand is why you want to call it. It doesn't take any parameters, doesn't return anything, and its body just creates (and then immediately destroys) a local object. If your example was less minimal and actually did something, you would know how to call it.

Comment: It's my stupid fault. C++ does not allow call a function outside of main function. In this case, the compiler assume the expression as a specialized function template.  this confused me.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, expressions (such as calling a function) can only occur inside functions (or inside initialisers of variables). Just putting a call outside of a function is an error.